# SQL Server Compact Edition ISNULL(sth, ' ') returns a boolean value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have an `Accounts` table with columns `name, password` and `email`. They are all type `nvarchar`.
I wrote a query like

```
SELECT name, password, ISNULL(email, 'eeee') 
FROM Accounts 
WHERE name = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password ='" + textBox2.Text + "'"
```

I read the email as `reader.getString(2)` since it is `nvarchar`.

As I read from the internet, if `email` is NULL, then it should return `eeee`. But it says `System.boolean` can not be translated to `System.String`.

How can I correct this? Why does it return a boolean value?

Comment: Sweet SQL injection you've got going on there

Comment: I think you wanted `ifnull()`

Comment: when i try ifnull, it doesn't recognize the function. on internet it says it is mysql, not microsoft sql server.

Comment: Read this: http://xkcd.com/327/ to get an idea of what SQL injection is and can do to your system, if you concatenate together your SQL statement without checking anything..... you should use **parametrized queries** instead!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/sql-server-ce-alternative-isnull-case-end-t1302099.html) `ISNULL` is not implemented in SQL Server CE. I would expect to see a syntax error raised, however.

Workaround: you can use `CASE WHEN email IS NULL THEN 'eeee' ELSE email END` or [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-3.5/ms174075(v=sql.100)). Preferably the latter.

Also use parameterised queries. If you don't know why you should, learn.

Comment: thank you it worked. I will accept your answer as soon as the 4 mins passed.