# SQL Joining by field that *may* be empty

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

In my SQL CE database I have three tables: `customer`, `list` and `customerlist` (a junction table between `customer` and `list` - as it is a many-to-many relationship).

I am trying to run a query that will display all current lists with also the number of customers who are currently subscribed to that list (counting from `customerlist` table).

Here is my current query:

```
select list.listid, count(customerlist.customerid) as numppl, list.ShortDesc
from list inner join customerlist on list.listid=customerlist.listid
group by list.ShortDesc, list.listid
order by numppl desc
```

The current structure of this database is:

```
[Customer]           [List]             [CustomerList]
CustomerId           ListId             CustomerListId
Name                 ShortDesc          CustomerId
Other details                           ListId
```

This currently returns all the lists who have customers currently assigned to them - but not lists which are empty. Empty lists are hidden.

I would like to modify this query to also display empty lists but I am struggling. My desired output is:

```
Name      numppl
listA     375
listB     45
listC     0
```

(In the example above, listC is currently not being returned).

Any thoughts on how to also show listC in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead with `ISNULL` to replace `NULL` with 0:

```
SELECT 
  list.listid, 
  ISNULL(count(customerlist.customerid), 0) AS numppl, 
  list.ShortDesc
FROM list 
LEFT JOIN customerlist ON list.listid = customerlist.listid
GROUP BY list.ShortDesc, 
         list.listid
ORDER BY numppl DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/526e8/1)

---

### Update

For SQL Server CE, try this:

```
SELECT 
  list.listid, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN customerlist.customerid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS numppl, 
  list.ShortDesc
FROM list 
LEFT JOIN customerlist ON list.listid = customerlist.listid
GROUP BY list.ShortDesc, 
         list.listid
ORDER BY numppl DESC;
```

Comment: This SQL is displaying "numppl" as 'FALSE' for every row, like Iswanto San's answer. Any idea how I can get numppl to display as a count?

Comment: Ok so I tried it in SQL Fiddle and it works. But please remember this is SQL CE and SQL Fiddle will not reflect it accurately.

Comment: @Teifi - OK, Sorry. You are right. I forgot that. So what is the problem you got in SQL CE. Please show me the error you got.

Comment: I am not getting any errors - the query works fine, just returns a boolean value when I want an int value :) Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890970/sql-server-compact-edition-isnullsth-returns-a-boolean-value
I am reading it now, it is news to me :)

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, that works great! I should have made it clearer I was using SQL CE :)

Comment: @Teifi You're welcome any time. No, it was clear that you are using SQL-CE, but it was my fault :( Thanks I just learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You must use [LEFT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) syntax.

```
select list.listid,  case when count(customerlist.customerid) is null then 0 else count(customerlist.customerid) end as numppl, list.ShortDesc
from list left join customerlist on list.listid=customerlist.listid
group by list.ShortDesc, list.listid
order by numppl desc
```

Or you can use [RIGHT JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Right_outer_join) :

```
select list.listid, case when count(customerlist.customerid) is null then 0 else count(customerlist.customerid) end as numppl, list.ShortDesc
from customerlist right join list on customerlist.listid=list.listid
group by list.ShortDesc, list.listid
order by numppl desc
```

Use COALESCE :

```
select list.listid,  coalesce(count(customerlist.customerid),0) as numppl, list.ShortDesc
from list left join customerlist on list.listid=customerlist.listid
group by list.ShortDesc, list.listid
order by numppl desc
```

Comment: Both of these queries return "numppl" as a boolean value, not as a COUNT(). How would I modify this query to display "numppl" as a count?

Comment: have you try to run the query ?

Comment: Yes - thats how I know that it is returning it as a boolean value ;)
"numppl" is always returning "FALSE" - not a number

Comment: sorry, It's SQL CE and ISNULL is not supported. I just edited my answer. http://devdump.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/sql-server-ce-3-5-isnull-not-supported/